# SQLCipher: is there a way to convert back a database file from 2.0 to 1.1.1.x?

Tags: sqlcipher

I am able to convert a SQLCipher file from 1.1.x to 2.0 (found an example "Convert from a 1.1.x to 2.0 Database with HMAC").
Is there a way to revert a database file to the oldest version (From 2 to 1) ?
Googling I found nothing
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via PRAGMA statements, the first must be run before you key the database, the second should occur after keying:

`PRAGMA kdf_iter = 4000;
 PRAGMA key = 'YourDatabaseKeyHere';
 PRAGMA cipher_default_use_hmac = OFF;`

This assumes you did not alter any other SQLCipher configuration settings.  A recommended alternative to the above scenario would be to upgrade your SQLCipher library to the latest 3.x version and perform a single time database format upgrade via another PRAGMA:

`PRAGMA cipher_migrate;`